# Why am I having an error when exporting .glb format on blender 3.0.1?

Tags: gltf

I am having an error when I try to export a 3d model as .glb format.
The operating system I am using is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
Blender version is 3.0.1.

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't use Blender under Linux, but I'd suggest updating to a supported version of Blender as a start. The nearest supported version to the one you're using is [3.3 LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-3/). If that doesn't work see if [Install numpy for blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440931/install-numpy-for-blender) helps.